# In Scheme, how can I write an iterative multiplication code (iter-multiply a b)

Tags: scheme

This is for recursive

```
(define (rec-multiply a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      0
      (+ a (rec-multiply a (- b 1)))))
```

Comment: Scheme doesn't have iterative looping constructs

Comment: @Shawn https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_idx_140

Comment: @WillNess `do` expands to a recursive function.

Comment: @Shawn of course, but it doesn't matter from the standpoint of a user / programmer. moreover, I'd also contend that any syntactically tail recursive function expresses iteration.

Comment: @Shawn Since Scheme has tail call optimization recursion is iterative as long as it is in tail position.

Comment: @Shawn In traditional Scheme lingo, a tail-recursive procedure implements an iterative process. See [section 1.2.1](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1) of SICP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme can offer a `named let`, something like a `for` loop.

In C++, the code would look something like this:

```
int mult (int x,int y) {
    int prod=0;

    for(int i=x; i>0; i--) {
        prod = prod + y;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

The Scheme equivalent is this:

```
(define (mult x y)
  (let loop ((times x)       ; init `times` as `x`
             (prod  0))      ; init `prod` as `0`
     (if (> times 0)
          (loop (- times 1)     ; new `times`
                (+ prod  y))    ; new `prod`
          prod)))
```

The "named `let`" is a `let` which has an additional label just after the `let` keyword, here `loop` (or any other valid name could also be used). In the `let` the initial values are defined, and when `loop` is invoked subsequently as a function, the new updated values are supplied as arguments, and we go back to the start of the "loop". If `times` reaches zero then the result, here `prod`, is returned.